# MVC asp.net, get data from textbox into javascript function in view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

any thoughts on this?

I'm using MVC2 in VS2010. I have javascript in my view to put markers on a google map. I need to get the address and distance from text boxes,

`<%= Html.TextBox("address") %>`
`<%= Html.TextBox("distance") %>`

to use as arguments in the function `drawMap(address, distance);` in my code.

Is there a register object I can use to access this? Also, having some issues using `<%= Html. (..) %>` in the `<script type="text/javascript"><script>` flags. I realise I should probably be implementing the MVC model here, and although use this to populate the textboxes on loading, can't pull the information from a textbox back out again on the POST back, to get values in the javascript function in the view.

Any suggestions greatly received! Thanks in advance.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// further question re: DropDownListFor<>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Is there also a simple way of getting information from:

`<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SavedAddress1, ViewData["StartLoc"] as SelectList) %>`

The SelectList for this is held in the Controller. Would I get which one had been selected from the controller in the POST? Or is there a way of determining which had been selected directly in the Javascript.

Many thanks

Comment: post some code please.. from view, from js

Answer (score 4):

To get the textbox value just use javascript

```
document.getElementById("address").value
```

or, with jquery, use

```
$("#address").val();
```

If you instead use a model passed to the view (which I prefer if the user don't have to change the value in the textbox) you can put that in the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
drawmap('<%= Model.Address %>', '<%= Model.Destination%>');
<script>
```

To have this value persisted in the form post, you can use the `Html.HiddenFor` tag

```
 <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address) %>
```

**Update to your edit**

For the dropdownlist, if you put it in the form tag, it will be binded to the model, so you will get it in the controller. While with javascript you can access the value the same way yuo used for the textbox.

Comment: The jquery part should be $("#address").val();

Comment: Thank you Iridio, the getElement() to great.